# How to add multiple parent node in XML using c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I want to return the response from WebAPI in the XML format and the response will be like this :
"**start response tag**" Request successfully processed "**end response Tag**"
"**start transid tag**> C4592 "**end transid tag**>"

Below Code return me the error.

```
 return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(string.Format("<response>Request successfully processed</response><transid>{0}</transid>", apiTransactionId), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
                };
```

Comment: Is the apiTransactionId a string?

Comment: @Palash Agrawal what response are you getting right now

Comment: No Worries Guys.. 
The below format is invalid XML format that's why it's not able to parse the same into XML. 
<response>Request successfully processed</response><transid>{0}</transid>

From below URL we can validate our XML file.
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp